# Prove $AC=\frac12AD$ in the triangle with given conditions.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

The question reads:

> Prove the following: if in triangle $ABC$, median $AM$ is such that $\text m\angle BAC$ is divided into the ratio $1:2$ and $AM$ is extended through $M$ to $,D$ so that $\angle DBA$ is a right angle, then $AC = \frac12AD$.

So far I have determined that the two angles must be $30^\circ$ and $60^\circ$. Also I tried making a rectangle and seeing if I could prove something that way, but each method reaches a dead end. Could anyone please provide a HINT, so that I am able to solve this problem with some progress? All help is appreciated!

Comment: Why is angle ABC divided (by median AM)?

Comment: The median need not cut $\angle A$ into $30^\circ$ and $60^\circ$ —that is, $\angle A$ need not be a right angle— but the result still holds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\angle{BAM}=\alpha, \angle{MAC}=2\alpha$.

Let $\overline{AC}=x, \overline{AD}=y, \overline{AM}=m$. Then, $\overline{AB}=y\cos{\alpha}$.

$\text{Area}(\triangle{BAM})=\frac{1}{2}(y\cos{\alpha})(m)\sin{\alpha}$
$\text{Area}(\triangle{MAC})=\frac{1}{2}(m)(x)\sin{2\alpha}$

Since $AM$ is a median, these two areas are equal. Equate them, and the result follows.

---

An entirely geometric solution is as follows: It makes use of the (given) fact that $\angle{BAC}=90^\circ$.

Construct the quadrilateral $ABDC$. This is a rectangle, since $AD$ bisects $BC$ (and we already have $\angle{BAC}=\angle{ABD}=90^\circ$).

Next, $\angle{MAC}=60^\circ$, so $\triangle{AMC}$ is equilateral (use the rectangle part). Thus, $AC=AM=MC$. Since the diagonals of a rectangle bisect at intersection, $AM=MD$. So, $AD=2AM=2AC$.

Comment: I apologize for this error, it was very stupid of me, I've made the correction to the post now

Comment: Additionally, how do we know that △MAC is equilateral? I can't seem to find a way to reason this with just the information we have.

Comment: @JaireetC Since we've a rectangle, $AM=MC$. So $\triangle{MAC}$ is isosceles. $\angle{MAC}=60^\circ$, so $\angle{MCA}=60^\circ$, and thus the 3rd angle also is $60^\circ$.

Answer (score 0):

Construct the parallelogram $ABNC$, with $\widehat{CAN}=2\widehat{BAN}$, the intersection of $AN$ with $BC$ gives $M$. Take $P$ midpoint of $AD$, you get $\widehat{BPD}=2\widehat{BAN}$, implying $BP=BN=AC$, done.

Best regards